# Prove scalar product in a normed vector space is an open mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I have the feeling this is a really obvious question, but I'm having trouble with it, here it goes:

Let $(X, ||\,||)$ be a normed vector space over $K$, prove that $\odot:K\setminus\{0\}\times X \mapsto X$, defined by 
$$\odot(\alpha,x)=\alpha x,$$
is an open mapping.

Since it was not stated in the problem, I'm assuming 
$$||(\alpha,x)||=|\alpha|+||x||.$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the space $X$ is banach it is an easy consequences of the open mappig theorem.

Anyway with the norm induced topology over $ X $ you in fact are resizing a ball so it is a ball again and it is open by definition of the topology. So the map sends open ball in open ball therefore it is open. This reasoning heavily rely on the "absolute omogeneity" of the norm we are working with

Recall the property of the norm $\| kx\| =|k|\|x\|$ and that the open set of the norm induced topology are unions of open balls $B_x(r) :=\{ y \in X | \| x-y\| <r \}$ so in fact if we prove that the map $\odot$ sends open balls in open balls we conclude.

The eps-delta argument is a bit "heavy" here. It is only a matter of the property of the norm. What is $\odot(k,B_x(r)) $? By using the definition of multiplication It is obvious that $\odot(k,B_x(r))= |k|B_x(r)=B_x(|k|r)$ (use the double inclusion and the invertibility of $k$)

Another analogue approach is to prove that $\odot$ is bijective (if $k\neq 0$) and for every $k$ is **continuous** (you can argue by definition). Think why it is sufficient this reasoning

**Addendum** in the language of the Topological Vector Spaces the previous reasoning is obvious. In fact another approach is to verify that norm induced topology is consistent with the axioms of a topological vector space

Comment: While I don't doubt the correctness of your answer, topology arguments exceed the scope of the material required for the solution (according to my professor), not to mention I don't have a good working knowledge of it. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: To be more precise, this is an $\epsilon-\delta$ problem.

Comment: @alonso  Mmh you want to speak about open maps without speaking of topology?

Comment: By open map I mean a function that sends norm-induced open sets into norm-induced opens sets.

Comment: Yes, so open balls in open balls

Comment: Yes. How would I proceed in an epislon-delta approach?

Comment: @alonsos Your epsilon delta is just a division by scalar factor :) I never saw such an approach for open maps. Continuity ok, but open no. If you want to use epsilon delta use it to prove continuity of your map and then follow second advice in the answer